# Java server not working on windows server

Tags: java, sockets, server

I'm trying to connect to java server socket placed on windows server from my computer.
I always got a timeout exception.
I have tried to disable firewall with no luck. it still gave me the same error.

`Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)`

server code

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
    public static int PORT = 3425;
    private ServerSocket server;

    public Server() throws IOException{
        server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("new socket attached " + socket.toString());
            System.out.println("waiting for message to read it");
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            byte [] bytes = new byte[1000];
            int text = input.read(bytes);
            System.out.println("message received");
            System.out.println(text);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 

    }

}
```

Client Code

```
public class Client implements Runnable {

    Socket socket;

    public Client() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("trying to connect");
        socket = new Socket("74.208.80.229", Server.PORT);
        System.out.println("connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("message sent");
            out.writeUTF("kasjdlkahdklajhdlkajsdhakljsdhlk");
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to ping that server and open a connection to the port you're using manually (e.g. by using telnet)? If that doesn't work there's probably a problem with your network infrastructure or a firewall (most likely on the server).

Comment: Yes I did, I used telnet to ping it but it's also didn't work, I disabled the firewall and tried again with same result. can you please give me more information about infrastructure problem.

Comment: I'm no networking expert but an ip address like `74.208.80.229` indicates the server is reachable via the internet. Thus it probably has its own firewall which might be blocking ports. Additionally there might be any number of networking devices between your computer and that server, any of which might also prevent access to the server or the port (something like an external firewall, proxy, nat etc.). If you can reach the server on some port (try port 80) it's probably a problem with a firewall blocking your custom port (most likely the server's, so contact the admin).

Comment: I tested port 80 and it's working, what you said about someone in the middle blocking our communication is the most probably the problem, do you know any fix for it ?

Comment: The fix is: contact whoever is responsible for that and let them change the configuration (and as I said, I highly suspect it's the server's firewall or the server's network's firewall). Other than that you could just go for port 80 and use webservices.